# Why `into` a map (`(into {} ,,,)`) works with `vectors` but not with `lists`, in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I can build a map with a list of vectors:

```clj
user=> (into {} (list (vector "a" "b") (vector "c" "d")))
{"a" "b", "c" "d"}
```

But if I try to do it with a list of lists, it fails:

```clj
user=> (into {} (list (list "a" "b") (list "c" "d")))
Execution error (ClassCastException) at user/eval3 (REPL:1).
class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.Map$Entry (java.lang.String and java.util.Map$Entry are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do `(into {} coll)` it is the equivalent of `(reduce conj {} coll)` so each element of your `coll` is used as the second argument to `conj` with a hash map as the first argument.

`conj` is built into `clojure.lang.RT` and it calls (in this case) `APersistentMap.cons()` to add the element which is here: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentMap.java#L24

As you can see from that, if the argument is a `MapEntry`, it'll get added to the hash map as a key/value pair: `(seq my-hash-map)` produces a sequence of `MapEntry` items.

If the argument is a vector that has two elements, it'll get added as a key/value pair where the key is the first element of that vector and the value is the second element of that vector.

Otherwise, it tries to convert the argument to a sequence and then *casts each element to `MapEntry` and adds it as a key/value pair*.

When you pass a list of vectors (two-element vectors), they are added as key/value pairs per the second case above. When you pass a list of lists, the third case is invoked and it tries to cast each element of your inner list to a `MapEntry` -- which fails because those elements are `String`'s.

Comment: TIL: cons and conj on maps work like merge:

`(conj {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 10 :c 30})` is the same as `(merge {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 10 :c 30})`. This happens because of the third case.

Thank you @sean-corfield !

Answer (score 1):

Not a Clojure expert, but I think key-value pairs are always represented as two-element vectors.

E.g., going in the other direction:

```clj
(seq {:a :b :c :d})
; => ([:a :b] [:c :d])
```

I suspect the fn `into` relies on this, as judging by your error message it appears to be looking for the `java.util.Map$Entry` interface, and (presumably) without each tuple being a vector this check fails.

Comment: Not quite: key/value pairs are `clojure.lang.MapEntry` objects in general but, as a convenience, there are a few places where a two-element vector is allowed to stand in for a `MapEntry`. `(class (first {:a :b :c :d}))` will report `clojure.lang.MapEntry` even though `(first {:a :b :c :d})` will print as a two-element vector.

Comment: @SeanCorfield This isn't exactly wrong: map entries *are* vectors. But not all vectors are map entries. `(vector? (first {1 2}))`

Comment: @amalloy That's because `clojure.lang.MapEntry` ultimately extends Clojure's persistent vector type _and_ implements `java.util.Map$Entry`. My point was specifically that `conj` has a special case that allows 2-element vectors _that are not map entries_ to be treated as if they were.